# How to avoid bottlenecks json processing with Apache Beam?

Tags: python, data-mining, apache-beam

I have a input with some transaction data in json input (in this case a file)

```
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 12:00:00", "customer": "customer-1", "page": "product", "product": "product-1" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 12:02:00", "customer": "customer-1", "page": "basket", "product": "product-1" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 12:04:00", "customer": "customer-1", "page": "checkout" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 13:00:00", "customer": "customer-2", "page": "product", "product": "product-2" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 13:02:00", "customer": "customer-2", "page": "basket", "product": "product-2" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 14:00:00", "customer": "customer-3", "page": "product", "product": "product-3" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 14:05:00", "customer": "customer-3", "page": "basket", "product": "product-3" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 14:10:00", "customer": "customer-3", "page": "product", "product": "product-4" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 14:16:00", "customer": "customer-3", "page": "product", "product": "product-5" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 14:20:00", "customer": "customer-3", "page": "basket", "product": "product-4" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 14:21:00", "customer": "customer-3", "page": "checkout" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 15:00:00", "customer": "customer-9", "page": "product", "product": "product-3" }
{ "timestamp": "2019-01-01 15:11:00", "customer": "customer-9", "page": "basket", "product": "product-3" }
```

The idea is be able to identify abandoned sessions, for example with more than 10 minutes idle. Transactions **checkedout** cannot be considered abandoned. The code to process is is below

```
import argparse
import json
import logging
import os

import arrow

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText, WriteToText
from apache_beam import ParDo, Pipeline, Map, GroupByKey, Partition
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, SetupOptions



class JsonCoder:
    """A simple encoder/decoder for JsonNL format"""

    @staticmethod
    def encode(stream):
        return bytes(json.dumps(stream.as_dict()), 'utf8')

    @staticmethod
    def decode(stream):
        return json.loads(stream)


class PageViews:
    """Datastructure to handle, store and view PageViews entries"""

    def arrow_to_json(self):
        return self.timestamp.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

    def __init__(self, timestamp, customer, page, product=None):
        self.timestamp = arrow.get(timestamp)
        self.customer = customer
        self.page = page
        self.product = product

    def as_dict(self):
        json_dict = {'customer': self.customer,
                     'page': self.page,
                     'timestamp': self.arrow_to_json()}

        if self.product is not None:
            json_dict['product'] = self.product

        return json_dict

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer};{self.arrow_to_json()};{self.page};{self.product} '

    def __repr__(self):
        repr_fmt = 'PageViews(customer={}, timestamp={}, page={}, product={}'
        return repr_fmt.format(self.customer, self.arrow_to_json(), self.page, self.product)


class JsonToPageViews(beam.DoFn):
    """A simple processor to be used while converting Json entries to PageViews struct"""

    def process(self, element, **kwargs):
        # Necessary to "normalize" the Json readings
        if 'product' not in element:
            element['product'] = None

        pv = PageViews(timestamp=element['timestamp'],
                       customer=element['customer'],
                       page=element['page'],
                       product=element['product'])
        yield pv


class OnlyExpired(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, **kwargs):
        customer, entries = element

        o_timestamp = entries[0].timestamp.timestamp
        checkout = False
        expired = False
        last_entry = None
        for num, entry in enumerate(entries[0:]):
            n_timestamp = entry.timestamp.timestamp
            d_timestamp = n_timestamp - o_timestamp
            o_timestamp = n_timestamp
            if d_timestamp > 60*10:
                expired = True

            if entry.page == 'checkout':
                checkout = True

            last_entry = entry

        if not checkout:
            expired = True

        if expired:
            yield last_entry


class GetTimestamp(beam.DoFn):
    """A Process just to check if timestamps where correctly assigned"""
    def process(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, **kwargs):
        yield '{} - {}'.format(timestamp.to_utc_datetime(), element)


def partition_fn(pageview, num_partitions=1):
    """Partition the customer based on customer_id"""
    customer_id = int(pageview.customer.split('-')[1])
    return customer_id % num_partitions


def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    """Entry point for main code"""

    # Processing Command Line  Arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input', help='Input files', default='input/page-views.json')
    parser.add_argument('--output', help='Output dir', default='output')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    # Create the pipeline
    p = Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    res = (p
           | 'Read JSON files' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input, coder=JsonCoder())
           | 'Convert JSON to Pageview' >> ParDo(JsonToPageViews())
           | 'Add Timestamps' >> Map(lambda entry: beam.window.TimestampedValue(entry, entry.timestamp.timestamp))
           | 'Create Group Key' >> Map(lambda entry: (entry.customer, entry))
           | GroupByKey()
           | 'Only Expired' >> ParDo(OnlyExpired())
           | 'Partition' >> Partition(partition_fn, 2)
           )

    res[0] | 'Save Part0' >> WriteToText(os.path.join(known_args.output, "abandoned-carts-part0"), file_name_suffix='.json', coder=JsonCoder())
    res[1] | 'Save Part1' >> WriteToText(os.path.join(known_args.output, 'abandoned-carts-part1'), file_name_suffix='.json', coder=JsonCoder())

    p.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARN)
    run()
```

I personally didn't like the way I have handled the idle sessions with a custom class `OnlyExpired`, since I need to save a session variable. I think is a bottleneck in case of streaming. How can I improve this code?

I also added a partition to split data when needed (in this case my customer name).

Comment: please, some moderator can create and assign the tag: `apache-beam` ?